# ObservableArray only populated with one record

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

My app is using durandalJS and KnockoutJS and one of my obserableArrays is not binding all the data that is returned via my api call..

**Binding:**

```
function refresh() {
        return conversationService.get(self.id()).done(function (result) {
            ko.object.map(self, result);
            system.log("Get Convo Data", result);
        });
    }
```

**Results from conversationService.get()**

[image: API Results]

**My naughty observableArray:**

```
    self.participants = ko.observableArray([]).extend({
        staffId: ko.observable(),
        userId: ko.observable(),
        name: ko.observable()
    });
```

**My Binding**

[image]

**Markup**:

```
<h4>Participants JSON</h4>
<pre data-bind="text: ko.utils.stringifyJson($root.participants())"></pre>
<pre data-bind="text: ko.utils.stringifyJson($root.participants().length)"></pre>
```

**jsFiddle** 
Here is a working jsFiddle that shows what I am doing but my issue is more w/ the api call getting and binding the data via durandal so I am not sure if it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/crathermel/7kH9C/4/

So my issue is that I don't really understand how to debug past hear and/or why the ViewModelBinder isn't taking all my items.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you make a fiddle ? Do you get any error ?

Comment: Could you post your view markup?

Comment: Okay posted a jsFiddle and also posted my markup although I am not sure if it will be helpful

Comment: Please post the code where you add items to `self.participants` and also your view where you are using it.

Comment: If it's Durandal specific use  https://github.com/dFiddle/dFiddle-1.2 (there's a [2.0.0pre](https://github.com/dFiddle/dFiddle-2.0) version as well) to reproduce.

Comment: What is this `refresh` function and how is it raleted `self.participants`? Beased on the `conversationService.get(self.id())` signature I'm quite sure that this call will **only return one*** item... but again without seeing more context we're just shooting in the dark.

Comment: So I cleaned up the order of things in my question to make this more clear.. conversationService.get returns everything I need for the viewmodel .. which is "self".. so self.particpipants is to the return but only one value from the array is mapped.. not all 3.  Reading this for help right now: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html

Comment: There's still not a lot Durandal specific code up there. If you could post a strip down version of the vm and the view that would be beneficial. You could use the http://github.com/dFiddle/dFiddle-1.2 to come up with a mockup. Save the API json return as .json and use $.getJSON to retrieve the file. In a Durandal app that should typically happen in  `vm.activate`. Make sure to return a promise if it`s an async call.

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough information to diagnose the problem, however I have forked your jsFiddle and have added a couple of use cases (refresh/refreshAll buttons) to show how you might bind values to observable Array. Here is the jsFiddle for you

http://jsfiddle.net/dhanasekaran/76jA5/2/

```
var vm = function () {
var self = this;
self.participants = ko.observableArray([]).extend({
    staffId: ko.observable(),
    userId: ko.observable(),
    name: ko.observable()
});
self.refresh = function () {
    var pp = {
        staffId: 2,
        userId: 102,
        name: 'Jack'
    };

    self.participants.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(pp));
};
self.refreshAll = function () {
    var pps = [{
        staffId: 2,
        userId: 102,
        name: 'Jack'
    }, {
        staffId: 3,
        userId: 103,
        name: 'Jim'
    }];

    self.participants(ko.mapping.fromJS(pps)());
    //or self.participants = ko.mapping.fromJS(pps);
};
```

}

Comment: I like using <p style="font-family:courier new"></p> instead of <pre></pre> tags for knockout data viewing because pre goes off the page to the right when the string gets long.